# Count records from multiple tables in real-time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count a record by current date from different tables and return as one row with different column in the new table. The code will update a record every three hours and insert new record if current date changes. I've current date and time data (2013-05-20 14:12:12) in "created_at" column. Here my current code:

```
require_once('./db_connect.php');
$dbcon = new db;

//test to see if a specific field value is already in the DB 
public function in_table($table,$where) {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE ' . $where;
  $result = mysqli_query($this->dbh,$query);
  $this->error_test('in_table',$query); 
  return mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0;
}

//running in background
while (true) {
   $select= "SELECT (SELECT CURDATE()) AS time," .
           "(SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) FROM tweets WHERE created_at= 'CURDATE() %') AS total_count," .
           "(SELECT COUNT(fid) FROM fun WHERE ftime= 'CURDATE() %') AS f_count," .
           "(SELECT COUNT(sid) FROM sad WHERE stime= 'CURDATE() %') AS s_count";

    $results = mysqli_query( $dbcon, $select );

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $time = $row['time'];
       $total = $row['total_count'];
       $fcount = $row['f_count'];
       $scount = $row['s_count'];

       $field_values = 'time = "' . $time . '", ' . 'total_count = ' . $total . ', ' . 'fun_count = ' . $fcount . ', ' . 'sad_count = ' . $scount;

       if ($dbcon->in_table('count','time= "' . $time . '"')) {
         $update = "UPDATE count SET $field_values WHEN time= '$time'";
         mysqli_query( $dbcon, $update );
       }
       else {
         $insert = "INSERT INTO count SET $field_values";
         mysqli_query( $dbcon, $insert );
       }
   }

   //update record every 3 hour
   sleep(10800);
}
```

With this code I can't get a count record. The result return `| 2013-05-18 | 0 | 0 | 0 |`. How can I correct this?

Comment: Print the query at runtime & fire it directly in mysql engine.. see if there is an error & if none then play with it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the parts where you have this:

```
WHERE created_at= 'CURDATE() %'
```

with this:

```
WHERE DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()
```

Your existing `WHERE` clause is comparing `created_at` to the string constant `CURDATE() %`, and they'll *never* match.

Comment: Thanks, still not solve the problems, in "created_at" column, I have current date and time (2013-05-20 15:12:11), How can I match with CURDATE() parameter only? Thanks

Comment: You can use the DATE() function to ignore the time piece of of the column. I've updated the answer to include this. Hope this helps!

Comment: *You can use the DATE() function* True, but using functions on a column may prevent the database from using indexes (if any exist). So it is better to [do something like this instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16654043/104223)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I'm also used mysqli_num_rows($result); I don't know COUNT() function seems not work with my tables.

Comment: @y45 - I do not think you need `mysqli_num_rows`. `COUNT` already returns the number of rows.  Though you may need to add an alias to access or differentiate the returned value. ie `SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) AS NumberOfTweets ... `

Comment: Hi Leigh, it was my faults, I'm always wrong to wrote a bracket before alias (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweets ) AS alias, anyway your code below and Ed is very useful, how I can set to accepted both of you in this forum?

Comment: @y45 - You can't. It is like the tag line in the old [Highlander movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_%28film%29) "*There can be only one*" .. answer ;-) However, you can vote up any answers or comments you found helpful. Edit: I just noticed [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) requires a 15+ reputation.

Answer (score 2):

I not familiar with PHP, but you can retrieve the count of all records dated any time today using:

```
     SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) 
     FROM   tweets 
     WHERE  created_at >= curDate()
     AND    created_at < date_add(curDate(), interval 1 day)
```

It is equivalent to saying

```
     ..
     WHERE  created_at >= (today at midnight *incusive*)
     AND    created_at < (tomorrow at midnight *exclusive*)
```

**Update:**

The advantage of this method is it is index friendly. While using `WHERE DATE(Column) = currDate()` works, it can prevent the database from using indexes on that column, making the query slower.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider with this code in the future, in case my code still work in progress :)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing against `created_at= 'CURDATE() %'`, which is looking for that exact string, not for the result of a function. If the field `created_at` is a date, it will never match.

And, you are doing that for all counts.

Comment: sorry for not clear, I have current date and time data in 'created_at' column. that's why I used CURDATE() %.

Comment: The answer you selected as correct is just telling you the same thing I was telling you. You were comparing `CURDATE()` between commas, which makes it a string and not an expression.